# Convert query from SQL Server to SQLite

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I want to get data from 2 tables ordering them by date: to get the cumulative balance for the customer.

The 2 tables that I want to get data from are my tables: transfers & trans_payments I had done this using an SQL server and here is the query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000000 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) num_col, 
    ID, cust_id, final, value, date, 
    SUM(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id
                       ORDER BY date, seq, ID) balance, 
    note
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ID, cust_id, final, 0, final balance, date, note, 0
     FROM 
         transfers 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 
         ID, cust_id, 0, value, - value, date, note, 1
     FROM 
         trans_payments) t (ID, cust_id, final, value, balance, date, note, seq)
ORDER BY 
    cust_id, date, seq
```

But I want to convert this query to use it in SQLite and here what I did until now :

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
(SELECT 1)) num_col, ID, cust_id, final, value, date, sum(balance) OVER 
(partition BY cust_id
ORDER BY date, seq, ID) balance, note
FROM (SELECT ID, cust_id, final, 0, final balance, date, note, 0
FROM transfers UNION ALL
SELECT ID, cust_id, 0, value, - value, date, note, 1
FROM trans_payments) t (ID, cust_id, final, value, balance, date, note, seq)
ORDER BY cust_id, date, seq
```

but I'm getting this error:`near "near "(": syntax error`

transfers:

```
ID        int   
cust_id   int   
tfrom     nvarchar(200) 
tto       nvarchar(200)
price     decimal(18, 2)
tax       decimal(18, 2)
final     Calculated 
tnumber   nvarchar(30)
note      nvarchar(MAX)
date      date
```

trans_payments:

```
ID       int
cust_id  int
value    decimal(18, 2)
method   nvarchar(30)
note     nvarchar(MAX)
date     date
```

Let's assume I have this data:

transfers:

```
ID    cust_id   final       date    
1      5        3000     22-09-2020  
2      5        1500     25-09-2020 
3      10       4000     28-09-2020
```

trans_payments:

```
ID    cust_id   value       date  
1      5        1000     22-09-2020
2      5        1500     23-09-2020
3      5        1000     01-10-2020
4      10       1000     28-09-2020
5      10       2000     01-10-2020
```

I want to create a view to show customers action on Purchases and Payments like this:

Customer 5:

```
cust_id   final    value    Balance    date      
5        3000        0       3000     22-09-2020 --- > Purchases 
5         0        1000      2000     22-09-2020 --- > payment
5         0        1500      500      23-09-2020 --- > payment
5        1500        0       2000     25-09-2020 --- > P
5         0        1000      1000     23-09-2020 --- > payment purchases
```

Here

Comment: I don't think SQLite supports column aliases after a table alias. Place them inside the subquery instead

Comment: @Charlieface I'm getting many errors I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite you should set the column aliases of a subquery inside the subquery.
Also, use `LIMIT` after the `ORDER BY` clause instead of `TOP`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) num_col, 
       ID, cust_id, final, value, date, 
       SUM(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY date, seq, ID) balance, 
       note
FROM (
  SELECT ID, cust_id, final, 0 value, final balance, date, note, 0 seq
  FROM transfers 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, cust_id, 0, value, - value, date, note, 1
  FROM trans_payments
)
ORDER BY cust_id, date, seq
LIMIT 1000000
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c9f54cdf8dc98cefb9b04b04a96cc590).